# Java static ArrayList<Object> remove issue

Tags: java

I have `static ArrayList<Batch>`. i want to remove which object contain productcode

This is my Batch Entity

```
public class BatchControl implements Parcelable{
  private String productCode;
  private String lotNumber;
  private String batchSerialNumber;
  private double quantity   ;
  private int sequence;
  private String productName;
  private String type;
  //Setter & getter
 }
```

This is my removing object

```
  static ArrayList<String> lstString = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (Iterator<Batch> i = lstString.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Batch value=(Batch )i.next();
        if(value.getSequence() == iVal) {
            lstString.remove(value);
        }
    }
```

`iVal` is Android TableLayout contain the row number.

```
        String number = txtNumber.getText().toString();
    iVal = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

But it didn't remove which object have iValue. Because of the resoan static arraylist so, each & every time when i remove size going to change.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `iVal` defined?

Comment: The code above can't compile. Show us your real code.

Comment: Show how you define the variables in `lstBatCtrl.get(k).getSequence() == iVal`.

Comment: It still doesn't compile. There's no way an `ArrayList<String>` returns an `Iterator<Batch>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an `Iterator` on a list, you can safely remove the current element (regarding position or index in the list) with [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).

```
for (Iterator<Batch> i = lstString.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Batch value=(Batch )i.next();
    if(lstBatCtrl.get(k).getSequence() == iVal) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Take into account that using `remove()` on a `static List` can yield to problems if there are concurrent modifications on the `List`. Citing `Iterator.remove()`'s javadoc:

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying
>   collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way
>   other than by calling this method

Answer (score 4):

You should use i.remove(), please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
  for (Iterator<Batch> i = lstString.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Batch value=(Batch )i.next();
        if(value.getSequence() == iVal) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
```